# Is Theon Greyjoy's member famous?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire, adaptation-comparison

In the recent *Game of Thrones* episode [*The Bear And The Maiden Fair*](https://tv.avclub.com/game-of-thrones-experts-the-bear-and-the-maiden-fai-1798176783) we heard the girls and the torturer talked about the supposed fame of Theon Greyjoy's penis.

> [Girls] *Don't you want us to see it? Oh, come on. Let us see it. Everybody talks about it*
>
> [Girls] *I felt something. Oh, Lord Greyjoy / [referring to the penis]As good as they say? / Mmh*
>
> [Torturer] *Should we see this cock everyone's always going on about? [...] Your famous cock must be very precious to you. Would you say it's your most
>   precious part?*

Is "it" also that famous in the book?

Answer (score 4):

That particular part of Theon does not seem to famous in the books. However Theon does like the company of women...

He is visitor of the whores in Winterfell and quite proud of how he "handles" them:

> Two serving wenches stood beneath the sign of the Smoking Log, the local alehouse. When Theon Greyjoy called out to them, the younger girl turned red and covered her face. Theon spurred his mount to move up beside Robb. "Sweet Kyra," he said with a laugh. "She squirms like a weasel in bed, but say a word to her on the street, and she blushes pink as a maid. Did I ever tell you about the night that she and Bessa—"
>
> *A Game of Thrones - Bran V*

He thinks that because of his station as Greyjoy women of lower birth should be pleased to have to opportunity to "be graced with his company";

> Theon swept his cloak off its peg and over his shoulders. "Fathers are like that," he admitted as he pinned the folds with a silver clasp. "Tell him he should be pleased. As many times as I've fucked you, you're likely with child. It's not every man who has the honor of raising a king's bastard." She looked at him stupidly, so he left her there.
>
> *A Clash of Kings - Theon I*

Again Theon believes himself to be special and that women will jsut fall in love with him after he has them;

> "Have you ever had a prince?" he asked her. "When you're wrinkled and grey and your teats hang past your belly, you can tell your children's children that once you loved a king."
>
> "Oh, is it love we're talking now? And here I thought it was just cocks and cunts."
>
> "Is it love you fancy?" He'd decided that he liked this wench, whoever she was; her sharp wit was a welcome respite from the damp gloom of Pyke. "Shall I name my longship after you, and play you the high harp, and keep you in a tower room in my castle with only jewels to wear, like a princess in a song?"
>
> *A Clash of Kings - Theon II*

Because *clearly* all the girl can wait to have a go with him;

> He might have put it down to a bad dream, but he did not remember dreaming. Kyra had worn him out. Until Theon had sent for her, she had lived all of her eighteen years in the winter town without ever setting foot inside the walls of the castle. She came to him wet and eager and lithe as a weasel, and there had been a certain undeniable spice to fucking a common tavern wench in Lord Eddard Stark's own bed.
>
> A Clash of Kings - Theon IV

So in the end Theon just seems to be [promiscuous and vain](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Theon_Greyjoy), but no mention on if he has the hardware to back this up.

Answer (score 2):

I may be wrong, but I am not sure there is a direct quote in the books that would attribute this kind of a reputation to Theon. That said, it is clear from the books that Theon enjoys the company of women, from which we can suppose that stories/gossip would have gotten around, and from these he may have acquired such a reputation. Particularly as common people love to gossip about the rich or the noble (much as people today gossip about celebrities).

Of course, as we know, A Song of Ice and Fire is a point of view series, so there is no reason to suppose that any of the characters would have reason to hear about or comment on such gossip. In television however, the viewer is not confined to the thoughts and experiences of one character at a time, which opens up the narrative to additional detail such as this. So I suspect this may be a case of the TV show embellishing the written narrative in order to enrich the experience and to emphasise a side of Theon's character that, whilst implicit in the books, may otherwise have been missed by a viewer if not explicitly mentioned.